# Neo4j, Cypher. Conditional merge

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a de-normalized csv file which looks something like this:

```
OrderId, OrderAmount, PersonId, PersonName, CarVIN, CarBrand, CarModel
1, 2500, 99, John Roe, JPN32132D2312DS, Toyota, Rav-4
2, 3200, 66, Harry Kone, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

And out if it, I am trying to create 3 new entities/label (Order, Person, Car) with relationships between them. A row in the csv represents a relation between an Order, Person and a Car. There's one condition that I'd like to apply here. If the corresponding id of an entity (OrderId, PersonId, CarVIN) is NULL, then we don't create an entity and the corresponding relation. Here is my code so far:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///source.csv'
AS row
MERGE (o:Order {Id:row.OrderId})
    ON CREATE SET 
        o.Amount = row.OrderAmount

MERGE (p:Person {Id:row.PersonId})
    ON CREATE SET 
        p.Name = row.PersonName
        
MERGE (c:Car {Id:row.CarVIN})
    ON CREATE SET 
        c.Brand = row.carBrand,
        c.Model = row.carModel
        
MERGE (o)-[:MADE_BY]->(p)
MERGE (p)-[:ORDERED]->(c)
```

The thing here is that for the second row:

> 2, 3200, 66, Harry Kone, NULL, NULL, NULL

I don't want to create neither the car entity nor the relation between person and a car.

Comment: Try looking here [conditional-cypher-execution](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/conditional-cypher-execution/)